# sqlite3 PYTHON Update

Tags: python, sqlite3

Добрый день уважаемые коллеги! Начал sqlite3. Команду UPDATE не понял. Вроде бы правильно написал. но значение на таблице не меняется. На самой DB Browser fo

SQLite Отрабатывает

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('employeers3.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

c='UPDATE dannie SET Salary_USD="30000$" WHERE Imya="Sergey"'
print(cursor.execute(c).fetchall())


connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Если не возвращает набора записей. Но команда даже не меняет содержимое в таблице. То есть через самой BD команда работает, но через  PyCharm не идет

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню тебе не нужно фетчить при апдейте. Попробуй так

```
import sqlite3


connection = sqlite3.connect('employeers3.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

with connection:
    query = "UPDATE dannie SET Salary_USD='30000$' WHERE Imya='Sergey'"
    cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/GUI/PYQRT/messageBOX.py", line 9, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked